# Implement SSL in IBM MQ in Node js

Tags: node.js, ssl, ibm-mq, jks

Trying to publish and subscribe message from IBM MQ 9 which has Cipher suite, user id, password, mykey.kdb file for SSL connection. we are able to connect through SSL with java. but want to do same thing with node js. While trying to do so we are getting `SSL_INITIALISATION_ERROR`. In `AMQERR01.LOG` we are Seeing below error block:

```
AMQ6090I:MQM could not display text for error 3456322
COMMENTINSERT3(SSLCIPH(' ') -> SSLCIPH(???))
```

can anyone help me on connecting to MQ using NOde js?

Comment: We have KDB file as well. when we tried importing it,  we are are getting " SSL_INITIALISATION_ERROR". I referred below link for code snippet https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/amqsconntls.js @JoshMc

Comment: KDB file is named as mykey.kdb

Comment: Where I can find file "AMQERR01.LOG"@JoshMc

Comment: its redistributable install @JoshMc

Comment: I am seeing this in the AMQERR01.LOG "AMQ6090I:MQM could not display text for error 3456322". In the error block I can see below line "COMMENTINSERT3(SSLCIPH(' ') -> SSLCIPH(???)) @JoshMc

Comment: Could you edit in the full error message from the `AMQERR01.LOG`.  I have edited your post to show you an example of how to paste in logs, just replace the two lines you provided with the full error, if there is more than one error message at the same time you attempt to connect, please provide this as well.  Based on the partial error I think it is saying either you are NOT specifying a cipher on the `SVRCONN` or on the client side, I can't tell with out more info.

Comment: Does your program look just like the one in the github link?  Did you make any changes to it?  For example the sample has a cipherspec setting but you mention in your question setting "Cipher suite", normally the term "Cipher suite" is used in relation to Java programs.  If you did make changes can you post the code by editing the question and adding it to the question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you have TLS working with Java, then in most likelihood you have the server configured correctly.

To run a Node.js MQ Client in TLS mode needs code that sets the cipher spec and identifies the location of the client keys.

```js
  const KEY_REPOSITORY = "../keys/clientkey";
  const CIPHER = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";


  var cno = new mq.MQCNO();

  // code that sets up cno object
  // like Options and MQCSP credentials


  var cd = new mq.MQCD();
  // And then fill in relevant fields for the MQCD
  // like ChannelName and ConnectionName

  // If running in TLS Mode 
  cd.SSLCipherSpec = CIPHER;
  cd.SSLClientAuth = MQC.MQSCA_OPTIONAL;


  var sco = new mq.MQSCO();

  sco.KeyRepository = KEY_REPOSITORY;
  // And make the CNO refer to the SSL Connection Options
  cno.SSLConfig = sco;
```

For java you are most likely using a .jks client keystore. For MQI based Clients (Node, Python, Go, C), you need a key database and stash file.

As you will need to have installed the MQI client, you can run the runmqakm tool to create them:

```
runmqakm -keydb -create -db clientkey.kdb -pw tru5tpassw0rd -type pkcs12 -expire 1000 -stash
```

and import the server's public key certificate into the client key database

```
runmqakm -cert -add -label QM1.cert -db clientkey.kdb -pw tru5tpassw0rd -trust enable -file key.crt
```

Notice that I have called the keystore and stash `clientkey`. You can call them what ever you want, but in your node.js code set
`sco.KeyRepository = KEY_REPOSITORY;`

to point at your equivalent of `clientkey`